# Please prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) = 0$$
>   for every integrable function. Show that $f(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]. $

Here is what I have so far:

Consider any $x \in [a,b].$ Consider any $y >0.$ Say $g(u) = 1$ for $x<u<x+y,$
and $g(u) = 0$ otherwise. Hence $\int_x^{x+y} f(u) du = 0.$ Hence $\frac{\int_x^{x+y} f(u) du}{y} = 0.$
tend $y = 0$ we get $f(x) = 0.$ Hence proved.

Is this correct?

Comment: I edited your question. Please double check I did not change anything (apparently, Yuval caught one mistake already).

Comment: Your proof sounds fine, just remember to invoke explicitly the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Well "dx" is missing...

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  Let $x_0$ be a point at which $f(x_0) \ne 0$;  Since $f$ is continuous there is an interval about $x_0$ in which $f$ is non-zero (can you prove this?).  Now, can you find a $g(x)$ for which $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx \ne 0$ given this information?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\int_{[a,b]}f^2=0$. Then, $f\ge 0$. If there exist $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$ Then, by continuity there exist an interval such that $f^2>0$ there and $\int_{[a,b]}f^2>0$, contradiction.